# Send $_SESSION to another page

Tags: php, session

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I continue a session from one page to another with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542427/how-do-i-continue-a-session-from-one-page-to-another-with-php)

I have this $_SESSION:

```
$_SESSION['user']['id'];
```

How can I send this, to another page with PHP?

Comment: Please learn what sessions are: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You do not need to "send" anything. `$_SESSION` is repopulated on each request when you call `session_start()` based on the session identifier in the `PHPSESSID` cookie sent by the browser.

Page A:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['user']['id'] = 3;
```

Page B:

```
session_start();
echo "User ID is: " . $_SESSION['user']['id']; //prints 3
```

Comment: Thanks! You just saved me a lot of time. Sorry for my stupidity.